# CGAL-Bindings (Python): Mesh from point cloud

Tags: python, c++, computational-geometry, cgal, finite-element-analysis

Im trying to do a finite element analysis for the Aorta of a pacient and i have a cloud of 3d points :

```
XYZ = array([[  23.4929,  126.6431,   78.2083],
             [  23.505 ,  123.2618,   76.1998],
             [  23.52  ,  124.356 ,   80.4145],
             ..., 
             [116.4752,  136.5604,   79.988 ],
             [ 107.8206,  136.9329,   73.7108],
             [ 154.0807,   91.6834,   91.9668]])
```

Visualization:

![Aorta][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U25dM.png

For that i need to get the following arrays:

> elem = {tetrahedrons made of 4 indexes}
> faces = {triangules made of 3 indexes}

But my question is:

> **How can i get, using CGAL-bindings (for Python), the 3d triangulation of the point cloud and then get the tetrahedrons and triangles for the Mesh?**

I already tried but the resulting 3d triangulation has indexes out of the len(XYZ) making no sense (result max index = 12000 vs len(XYZ) = 1949).

If someone that already used CGAL-bindings for python can help me with how to use it for this purpose or help me to comprehend the C++ code from CGAL Mesh Generation Examples, please :(.

http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html#Chapter_3D_Mesh_Generation

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_criteria_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Labeled_image_mesh_domain_3.h>
#include <CGAL/make_mesh_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Image_3.h>
// Domain
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Labeled_image_mesh_domain_3<CGAL::Image_3,K> Mesh_domain;
// Triangulation
typedef CGAL::Mesh_triangulation_3<Mesh_domain>::type Tr;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<Tr> C3t3;
// Criteria
typedef CGAL::Mesh_criteria_3<Tr> Mesh_criteria;
// To avoid verbose function and named parameters call
using namespace CGAL::parameters;
int main()
{
  // Loads image
  CGAL::Image_3 image;
  image.read("data/liver.inr.gz");
  // Domain    
  Mesh_domain domain(image);
  // Mesh criteria
  Mesh_criteria criteria(facet_angle=30, facet_size=6, facet_distance=4,
                     cell_radius_edge_ratio=3, cell_size=8);
  // Meshing
  C3t3 c3t3 = CGAL::make_mesh_3<C3t3>(domain, criteria);
  // Output
  std::ofstream medit_file("out.mesh");
  c3t3.output_to_medit(medit_file);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your input is a set of points, you need a reconstruction algorithm as the mesher need a domain defined by a grey level image, a polyhedral surface, ...

Comment: As @sloriot said, you cannot directly use the algorithms from CGAL 3D Mesh Generation. You should use a reconstruction method. About your point set, are the points supposed to be on the boundary of your object, or are they inside? You could try to use the 3D Alpha Shapes, from CGAL, but that package is not yet in cgal-bindings.